# How to retain the duplicate values during the JSON stringify operation

Tags: javascript, html, json, vue.js

I am obtaining the response from the server in `JSON` format. This `JSON` may constitute objects with duplicate `Keys`. When I was displaying the result the duplicate key values were getting committed. After debugging I found out that this is happening because of the `JSON.stringify` method that I am performing to format the code before providing to the front-end.

As of now when I perform the `JSON.stringify` then it removes the `duplicate` entries and provides only the `last` value for the duplicate `keys` however I would like to retain everything.

```
var obj = {name: "John", age: 30, name: "New York"};
var result = JSON.stringify(obj).replace(/\_/g, '');
console.log(result);
//{"name":"New York","age":30}
```

As we can see the `first name` has been committed. How to modify the code so we can retain all values of the duplicated key?

Please Note:
As of now, I have provided the sample code that has the duplicate key `name`. However, when I am getting the response from the server I am unaware of what `key` might be duplicated so I am looking for a general solution that can work for everything rather than hard-coded logic that works only for `name`.

Any suggestions or workarounds would be really appreciated.

Comment: _"This JSON may constitute objects with duplicate Keys"_ - That's not possible. If you try to add a key more than once it just overwrites the content of the previous instance. Fix the source of the JSON if you need all the values.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks a lot for the response it is not possible to fix the source as the `JSON` values having duplicate is perfectly valid in my case and they adhere to `JSON-Schema` as they are part of the custom elements provided by user. It can read something like this `"google:field":"Value1","google:field":"Value2"` etc. As per the application its allowed to have duplicate keys. Also, I am not allowed to make any modifications to it. I just want to write some custom scripts to handle these duplicate entries in the JSON.

Comment: _"As per the application its allowed to have duplicate keys."_ I don't understand.  The coding standards determines how you use the code, not the application definition.  If a program required gravity not to exist, would gravity cease to exist?

Comment: The problem is not with the JSON Schema. The problem is it's not possible to have an object like `var obj = {name: "John", age: 30, name: "New York"};` in JavaScript. Try running  this code, you will get an object with a single `name` field, and its value will be `"New York"`.

Comment: If you get a JSON string from a server with duplicate keys, like `{"name": "John", "age": 30, "name": "New York"}`, then JSON.parse will create `{name: "New York", age: 30}`.

Comment: @HoldOffHunger As per the JSON documentation it's recommended not to have a duplicate key that does not mean it's forbidden. Moreover, if you try to check if the `JSON` is valid for `{name: "John", age: 30, name: "New York"}` then you would get as valid but it throws a warning, not an error.

Comment: _"As per the application..."_ - ECMAScript doesn't care about your application. An object can only have unique keys. If you have to work with that (imho invalid) JSON you have to write your own JSON parser. Good luck with that...

Comment: It's not forbidden to have dupe keys in JS objects. They are just ignored. Same for JSON,. The way you try it to make it work is not JSON but something else, so you need custom parser, as it was said. A proper way is to fix this in a place where this JSON is produced. If it was expected to provide multiple values with dupe keys, that's a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Json objects don't allow duplicated keys.
If you execute just:

```
var obj = {name: "John", age: 30, name: "New York"};
console.log(obj)
```

You will see that you have already lost the first "name" value.

The only work around that I can think of, is to never transfor the received JSON String to an Object.

Or you can manually write a logic to split this json string by commas, and transform it into a JSON object according to you need, but without duplicated keys, for example:

```
{name: ["John", "New York"], age: 30};
```

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: Thanks for the response, I myself have provided this in the question. I am requesting a work-around to retain the duplicate key in the `JSON`. As per the JSON documentation, it's recommended not to have a duplicate key that does not mean it's forbidden.

Comment: @Andreas https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp

Comment: That's just one of the many examples why w3schools.com is still an awful resource for anything related to HTML/CSS/JavaScript. It's either an object or JSON (a string). There's no such thing as a "JSON Object". Just read the linked article.

Comment: @Andreas Quote from the article you linked :
"While Object literals are not “JSON Objects,” there really is a JSON object ..."

Comment: Did you follow that link? It talks about `JSON` in your browser. That thing with `.parse()` and `stringify()`.

Comment: @Andreas So, you are saying that is indeed something called JSON Object. Now I don't know anymore what you are trying to convice me of. I thought you were trying to convice me that "there is no such a thing as JSON object".

Comment: @BATMAN_2008 I updated the answer with the only work around I could think of.